# Understanding Rudin's proof of: Every bounded sequence in $R^k$ contains a convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I am trying to understand the proof for:

> **Theorem 3.6b:**
> Every bounded sequence in $R^k$ contains a convergent subsequence

which is as follows in Baby Rudin:

> This follows from (a), since Theorem 2.41 implies that every bounded subset of $R^k$ lies in a compact subset of $R^k$.

(a) refers to:

> If $\{p_n\}$ is a sequence in a compact metric space $X$, then some subsequence of $\{p_n\}$ converges to a point of $X$

and Theorem 2.41 is:

> **2.41** $\ \ $ **Theorem** $\ \ $ *If a set $E$ in ${\bf R}^k$ has one of the following three properties, then it has the other two:*
>
> $\quad(a)\ \ $ *$E$ is closed and bounded.*
> $\quad(b)\ \ $ *$E$ is compact*.
> $\quad(c)\ \ $ *Every infinite subset of $E$ has a limit point in $E$.*

My interpretation of Rudin's proof of Theorem 3.6b is:

**Proof**: Any bounded sequence of $R^k$ is clearly contained in a k-cell and since each k-cell is compact (Rudin's Theorem 2.40), every bounded sequence of $R^k$ lies in a compact subset of $R^k$. Now, let $\{p_n\}$ be an arbitrary sequence in $R^k$. Then, by Theorem 3.6a, some subsequence of $\{p_n\}$ converges to a point of $R^k$ and we are done.

**My question:** Is my interpretation of the proof correct? Is it the interpretation that Rudin was pointing to?

Comment: I also agree with you, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is perfectly fine, well done!

---

I'll also add that it is interesting to compare and contrast this result with Theorem 2.42 and its proof (given on page 40):

> **2.42$\quad$Theorem (Weierstrass)$\quad$** Every bounded infinite subset of $R^k$ has a limit point in $R^k$.
>
> **Proof$\quad$** Being bounded, the set $E$ in question is a subset of a $k$-cell $I \subset R^k$. By Theorem 2.40, $I$ is compact, and so $E$ has a limit point in $I$, by Theorem 2.37.

Here, Theorem 2.37 states that "If $E$ is an infinite subset of a compact set $K$, then $E$ has a limit point in $K$."